# How do you deal with NaT when creating a function?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate the days between two dates depending on certain rules.

I have the following code that kinda works, but the last "elif" is not working because I can't seem to do a "is not NaT"...

```py
    def life(x):
        active = x.Active
        mind = x.MinDate
        close = x.CloseDate
        today = pd.to_datetime(date.today())

        if active == 1:
            return (today2 - mind)
        elif active == 0 and close:
            return (close - mind)
        elif active == 0 and not close:
            return datetime.timedelta(days=0)
        else:
            return 'CHECK'
```

I also tried 'close == None', but I still won't get the '0 days' on the output.

Comment: Have you tried `isnat`? Also, my `pd.Series.where` sense is tingling.

Comment: Mike thanks for your reply, I couldn't make it work with np.isnat() but I found pd.NaT and I changed the code to the following:

elif active == 0 and not close is pd.NaT:
        return (close  - mind)
    elif active == 0 and close is pd.NaT:
        return datetime.timedelta(days=0)